# How can push data in sSearch using datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data-table which is working properly, now i want to add a filter, I have added a input filed with submit button. Basically data-table has a already filter, when user write something an ajax call going to server, (On debugging) data-table filter value showing on equal to sSearch, now i want exactly this, currently (added field) an ajax call also going when user but its value not showing on equal to sSearch. Can any body let me know how can solve the issue? Thanks in advanced

```
$(function(){
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // dataTables default values / settings starts {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // bootstrap
    $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
        "bootstrap": {
            "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
                var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                    }
                };

                $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
                    '<ul>'+
                        '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                        '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'
                );
                var els = $('a', nPaging);
                $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
                $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
            },

            "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
                var iListLength = 5;
                var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
                var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
                var i, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

                if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                    iStart = 1;
                    iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                }
                else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
                    iStart = 1;
                    iEnd = iListLength;
                } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
                    iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                    iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                } else {
                    iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                    iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
                }

                for ( i=0, iLen=an.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
                    // remove the middle elements
                    $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                    // add the new list items and their event handlers
                    for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                        sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                        $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                            .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                            .bind('click', function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                                fnDraw( oSettings );
                            } );
                    }

                    // add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                    if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                        $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                    }

                    if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                        $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }); // bootstrap ends

    // additional functions for data table
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
    {
        /*console.log( "iStart: " + oSettings._iDisplayStart );
        console.log( "iEnd: " + oSettings.fnDisplayEnd );
        console.log( "iLength: " + oSettings._iDisplayLength );
        console.log( "iTotal: " + oSettings.fnRecordsTotal() );
        console.log( "iFilteredTotal: " + oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() );
        console.log( "iPage: " + Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ) );
        console.log( "iTotalPages: " + Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength ) );*/

        return {
            "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
            "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
            "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
            "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
            "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
            "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
            "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
        };
    } // ends

    // error throwing method
    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';

    // dataTable default settings
    var oDefault_dataTables = {

        // sDom {
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'" + //---------------- 1: row-fluid starts
                    "<'span12'" + //----------------2: span12 starts
                        //"<'span1'C>" + 
                        "<'span2'l>" +
                        "<'span10'f>" +
                        //"<'span6'T>" +
                    ">" + // 2: span12 ends
                ">" + // 1: row-fluid ends
                "<'center'r>" +
                "<'row-fluid'" + //---------------- 1: row-fluid starts
                    "<'row-fluid't>" +//---------------- 3: tbl row-fluid starts & ends
                ">" + // 1: row-fluid ends

                "<'row-fluid'" + //---------------- 1: row-fluid starts
                    "<'span12'>" + //---------------- 4: span12 starts
                    "<'span12 center'lp>" +
                    "<'span12 center'>" +
                ">", // 1: row-fluid ends
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        /*********************************************
        l - Length changing // record limit dropdown
        f - Filtering input // Search Box
        t - The table!
        i - Information
        p - Pagination
        r - pRocessing
        < and > - div elements
        <"class" and > - div with a class
        Examples: <"wrapper"flipt>, <lf<t>ip>
        *********************************************/
        ////////////////////////////////////////////// }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // basic setup {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true, // Enable or disable automatic column width calculation
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
            "sZeroRecords": "No records to display",
            "sProcessing": "<img src='" + THEMEURL + "img/ajax_loaders/ajax-loader-5.gif'>",
            "sSearch": "",
        },
        // }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // pagination setup {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap", // [bootstrap, full_numbers, simple, simple_numbers, full]
        "iDisplayStart": 0, // where to start from db
        "iDisplayLength": DATATABLE_LIMIT, // db Limit
        "aLengthMenu": DATATABLE_aLengthMenu, //[[5, 15, 25, 50, 100], [5, 15, 25, 50, 100]], // record get limit dropdown
        // }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // server side setup
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": DATATABLE_cnt + '?uri_str=' + URI_STR,
        /*"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            //console.log(aoData);
            //aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
        },*/

        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
            // initialize js functions
            docReady();
        },
        "aoColumns": DATATABLE_aoColumns,
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    } // oDefault_dataTables ends

    // initializing
    var oST = $.extend(true, {}, oDefault_dataTables);
    // datatable
    var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable(oST);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // dataTables default values / settings ends }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


});
```

### For Second Filter

```
oTable.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
          function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
             var listingcity = document.getElementById('cityorzip').value;
            // push({"name":"cityorzip", "value":$('input.cityorzip').val() });
            //alert("test"+listingcity);
          }
       );
       ///aoData.push({"name":"cityorzip", "value":$('input.cityorzip').val() });
       $('#cityorzip').keyup(
            function() { oTable.fnDraw();
                //push("{'name':'cityorzip'",+ "'value':$('input.cityorzip').val() }")
            } 
        );
```

Comment: Have you looked at `fnServerParams`?